# App crashing on operation on Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

We have been trying to set a picture in our app, using a bitmap fecthed from a server. Problem is, the app keeps crashing on every operation we use on this Bitmap. `

```
    String jsonInString = img;
    image = gson.fromJson(jsonInString, Bitmap.class);
}
```

`
Is the code where we get the bitmap.

Then if we try to resize the Bitmap or set an ImageView with it, the app closes out, providing no errors. We have looked at the unfiltered part of the log aswell.

We have tried setting the ImageView to null, among other things, but it seems the error is in the bitmap.

Comment: He get it in the String and after convert it in Bitmap.

Comment: please add the stacktrace

Comment: what you are getting from the server, path of the image on server or data.

Comment: We get a String from the server, so data.